# How to validate required checkboxlists when each property's value of them is dymanic using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, checkboxlist

Below is my form with two groups of checkboxlist.

```
<form id="my-form">

    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknown-name-1[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknow-name-1[]" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknow-name-1[]" value="_other" data-target-text-input="text-input-other-option-unknow-name-1"> Others 
    <input type="text" id="text-input-other-option-unknow-name-1" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknown-name-1[]">


    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-2" name="unknow-name-2[]" value="House"> I have a house<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-2" name="unknow-name-2[]" value="Apartement"> I have an apartement<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-2" name="unknow-name-2[]" value="Vila"> I have a vila<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-2" name="unknow-name-2[]" value="_other" data-target-text-input="text-input-other-option-unknow-name-2"> Others 
    <input type="text" id="text-input-other-option-unknow-name-2" class="unknown-name-2" name="unknow-name-2[]">

</form>
```

All the class or ID or name of each checkbox is dynamic which means I don't know what the value of each attribute will be on the moment that the view is rendered, neither the numbers of groups of the checkboxlist, but two groups above will be used as an example of code snippet.

Validation rules:

Each checkboxlist is required at least one option to be checked. The last option is `_other`, if this option is checked, its input field is required.

I have spent hours to write the dynamic validator with `JavaScript` but I still cannot get it done. I hope some of you can help me! How can I write a dynamic validator with `JavaScript`, `not in jQuery`, that can check these conditions? Note: There can be one, two, three or more groups of checkboxlist, the value of all attributes of each checkbox is unknown beforehands. If necessary, more attributes can be added to the checkbox but the value of them needs be dynamic.

Comment: Can you show us any validation code that you already have? Are you just trying to validate that values are checked (and input field completed if required) or do you care about validating the values are one of expected set of values (i.e. not changed)?  In other words, do the values actually matter or are you only looking to validate input state?

Comment: Why dont you add them a second static class whose only purpose is validation?

Comment: Otherwise the only thing I can think of is having a .each() loop with a GLOBAL variable isChecked and if you see a true you set the variable to true and break out. (PS you will need a if statement to check checkbox vs text field)

Comment: Are you getting JSON and you are passing it to a component that creates a form or you are getting HTML?

Comment: For you is it possible to maintain divs for each group. so that you can check the checked fields for the each group by their div name/id/class.

Comment: @MikeBrant: the value of the input field does not matter. If the last option with the value `_other` is checked, the input text field is required.

Comment: @sinanspd if I use a.each() loop how can I distinguish one group of checkboxlist from another. If I use a.each() loop, lets say the first group of checkboxlist passed, set a global variable to true but the second group of checkboxlist failed, the form will be valid still because the global variable was set to true by the first group of checkboxlist.

Comment: @Rajesh I get the data from the database and compose the HTML form with that. So I will not know how many checkboxlists will be created and what the value of name or class or ID will be, but this can be set while composing HTML form.

Comment: @OConnor following is a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p228yvhk/). check if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an handler to submit event and retrieve all checkbox for current form, and to checks if one checkbox is checked use the "checked" property (easy, isn't it ? :)).

Simple solution :

```
var form = document.getElementById('my-form');

function validate(e) {
    // "this" is the current form which has been submitted
    // so we get all checkboxes for this form
    var checkboxes = this.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'); 
    var isValid = false;

    for (var c = 0; c < checkboxes.length; c++) {
        if (checkboxes[c].checked) {
            isValid = true; break;
        }
    }

    if (!isValid) {
        alert('One choice at least required.');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

Full example : http://jsfiddle.net/Reeska/a228Lko0/

Advanced solution :

You can apply this method to an advanced usage, first we need to mark which block or field need to be validate, to do that, we need to use css classes and data-attributes :

```
<form id="my-form">
   <div class="validate" data-validator="checkbox-required" data-name="Group 1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknown-name-1[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknow-name-1[]" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknow-name-1[]" value="_other" data-target-text-input="text-input-other-option-unknow-name-1"> Others 
      <input type="text" id="text-input-other-option-unknow-name-1" class="unknown-name-1" name="unknown-name-1[]">
   </div>
   <hr />
   <div class="validate" data-validator="checkbox-required" data-name="Group 2">
    ...
   </div>
   <input type="submit" val="submit" />
</form>
```

For each items with `validate` class, I indicate which validation type I want with data-attributes `data-validator`, and in JS I will create one function by validation type :

```
var validators = {
    'checkbox-required' : function() {
        var checkboxes = this.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'); 
        var isValid = false;

        for (var c = 0; c < checkboxes.length; c++) {
            if (checkboxes[c].checked) {
                isValid = true; break;
            }
        }     

        return {
            valid: isValid,
            msg: (!isValid ? 'One choice at least required.' : '')
        }
    }
};
```

Finally, for each `validate` item I apply its validator function on submit :

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var items = this.querySelectorAll('.validate');
    var errors = [];

    for (var it = 0; it < items.length; it++) {
        var data = items[it].dataset;
        var validator = data['validator'];

        if (!validator || !validators[validator]) {
            console.log('Unknown validator : ' + validator);
            continue;
        }

        var test = validators[validator].call(items[it]);

        if (!test.valid) {
            errors.push((data.name ? data.name + ": " : '') + test.msg);  
        }
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // if error is detected, cancel submit
        e.preventDefault();  

        alert(errors.join("\n"));
    }
});
```

That's it, and you can add other validators type.

Full advanced example : http://jsfiddle.net/Reeska/a228Lko0/5/

Comment: I think your validation will also pass when the first group of checkboxlist is valid but the second group of checkboxlist is not valid. Won't it?

Comment: You're right, this example is a simple how-to, it's not the full solution, but I will complete it with more advanced features.

Comment: please! thank you beforehand. I stuck with this for days.

Comment: I tried your advanced code. It works very good! Can you modify your code for one more condition when the last option of any checkboxlist is checked, it has the value `_others`. If so, the input text field right after that last checkbox option may not be blank.

Comment: You can add a specific validator for this case, add `validate` class to _other input, create a `other-required` validator which It will checks if the input, targetted by the `data-target-text-input` attribute, is empty or not. In `other-required` function you get 'other' textfield with `var tf = this.querySelector('#' + this.dataset['targetTextInput']);`